# javascript/jquery to change location.href

Tags: javascript, window.location, submit-button

This is my HTML

```
        <form id="procurar-novo">
          <input type="text" name="procurar" placeholder="Pesquisar no Site" value="">
          <input id="procurar-submit" type="button" value="&rsaquo;">
        </form>
```

And this is my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#procurar').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //edited
      window.open = ('http://www.psicotropicus.org/'+'/busca'+encodeURIComponent($('#procurar-submit').val()), '_blank');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

The ideai is that by clicking on submit, the javascript/jquery will get the #procurar-submit value and add it on the URL and redirect the user.

The _blank still not works

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sooooo, what is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work the way I coded.

Comment: why not just submit the form as a normal `GET`?

Comment: How about: `<form action="http://psicotropicus.org" method="GET">`?

Comment: I got redirected to http://psicotropicus.org/?procurar=aaa and in the same window. I should be redirected to http://psicotropicus.org/busca/aaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't have an action specified on your form tag. Why not just change the second input element from `type=submit` to `type=button`. Then you can bind a click event on that button and have full control of what happens next. You don't have to worry about preventing a default submit action. You could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#procurar-submit', function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.psicotropicus.org/busca'+$('input[name="procurar"]').val();
  });
});
```

To open a new window like on a '_blank' you could change the code to be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#procurar-submit', function() {
    window.open('http://www.psicotropicus.org/busca'+$(input[name="procurar"]).val(), '_blank');
  });
});
```

But be careful with pop-up blockers

**EDIT**
I changed the selector that gets the value of the text field.
I would maybe add a class or id on that text field so it can be identified apart from others. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TN4CB/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed the type for "button" but the javascript doesn't seem to work still. I get redirect to http://rflbrz.zz.mu/psico/?procurar=lalala instead of what you wrote.

Comment: That domain isn't even close to the same as in the code? Is something else different?

Comment: Actually, changing the type to button made it not work. When it was submit type, I had been at least redirectioned to the URL above.

Comment: It's a domain I use to test stuff.

Comment: It just seems lazy to use an input type=submit when you are not submitting a form. If you really want to use a form, why not do something like @zzzzBov mentioned in the comments and actually use the action?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just put type=submit because I thought it was the right thing to do. Will replace for button.

Comment: Well both ways will end up working, I don't want to say there is only one hard and fast way. It is just my preference that if I am not using the default characteristics of the element, and I even have to add code to prevent them, why not just use an element where I can put my own custom code.

Comment: I apologize, the `this` isn't going to get the correct element, Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TN4CB/1/)

Comment: The fiffle is not working here :/ Tested on chrome and firefox

Comment: Oh, I had to turn on the jquery library, my bad.
It worked, but it's opening on the same window! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use window.open with second parameter _blank

```
window.open('url', '_blank');
```

Try this also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#procurar').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //edited
      window.open = ('http://www.psicotropicus.org/'+'/busca'+encodeURIComponent($('#procurar-submit').val()), '_blank');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Last edit:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#procurar-novo').submit(function(e) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      //edited
      var url = 'http://www.psicotropicus.org'+'/busca'+ encodeURIComponent('&' + $('input[name=procurar]').val());
       window.open(url, '_blank');
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>

<form id="procurar-novo">
          <input type="text" name="procurar" placeholder="Pesquisar no Site" value="">
          <input id="submitsss" type="submit" value="&rsaquo;">
</form>
```

**Please consider names and ids of the form elements :)**

Comment: could you help me with this:

The idea is that by clicking on submit, the javascript/jquery will get the #procurar-submit value and add it on the URL and redirect the user.

Opening it on a new tab is just a secondary problem.

Comment: it is still redirecting me to http://www.psicotropicus.org/busca?procurar=aa when I search "aa" instead of that link. and it's not opening in a new tab. but I guess we are almost there!

Comment: @Rafael: use different browser and check again, window.open is the only solution

Comment: ok. but the URL is still not going right. does the input type make difference?

Comment: I tried, didn't work. I've just edited my post for you to see the mark up and the last script I tried.

Comment: @Rafael: sorry, here is final update [see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DrLd3/) I also updated my post :)